# Why isn't my pip log owned by me? How to resolve the error?

Tags: python, installation, pip, sudo

When I tried to pip install anything, i get the following warning:

```
~$ sudo pip install -U scikit-learn
The directory '/home/alvas/.cache/pip/log' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the debug log has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/alvas/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/alvas/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

**Why isn't my pip log own by me?** How to I resolve the problem?

**Is there a problem at all to see that warning?**

When I've used `sudo -H pip install -U scikit-learn`, the warning disappears.

When I've tried `sudo -H`, it sets the HOME variable to my directory but I'm already at home directory? So what is happening here? Is there something wrong in my bash variable setting?

Comment: Have you tried using `-H` as suggested? Not using `sudo`? What research have you done, with what results?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ahhhhh, yeah, i've `sudo` set environment at some point a few days ago... must be the beer~~ Thanks!!!